# visx threshold y values issue

Tags: reactjs, visx

So I have set up two line charts using visX, and what I need is the space between them to be filled with color. I've tried using the Threshold component, but the props seem to be wrong, any idea how to achieve this?

[image: expected outcome]

Here is a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-resonance-5hbs58?file=/src/App.js